# Remove default tooltip Google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

**Hello** How I can remove to default Tooltip from google maps, So I'd like to replace this tooltip with my Div.

**I tried to use this code but nothing:**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function (e) {
e.mb.target.removeAttribute('title');
```

**Here my code:**

```
 marker.addListener('mouseover', function () {
    $('.contact-info').show(1000);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removing default mouseover tooltip from marker in google-maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001036/removing-default-mouseover-tooltip-from-marker-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this example :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple?hl=fr

You can do something like this to show a custom tooltip for a marker :

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString
});

marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v8yrcs6h/

Comment: Thank you, I've showed this example before, I'd like to remove default tooltip!!

Comment: When you create your marker dont add any title like this you ll not have to remove it ;). Moreover if you want to remove the title property the good way is  `delete marker['title'];`