# Removing title tag attribute from google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, google-maps

[image]

I want to completely remove the `title` tag when the user mouseovers on the marker. This is what I have tried so far.

```
jQuery("[title]").removeAttr("title");
jQuery("*").removeAttr("title");
```

Neither works.

I have referred to the below solutions also.

**[removing default mouseover tooltip from marker in google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001036/removing-default-mouseover-tooltip-from-marker-in-google-maps)**

**[title of a marker of google map marker API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279199/title-of-a-marker-of-google-map-marker-api)**

But could not find any solution that actually removes the title tag.

Comment: Are you using Google Maps API?

Comment: I am using google maps WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the script set properties: title: ''.

**Updated**
and it worked: `http://jsfiddle.net/edf3gwuk/`

```js
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function point(lat, long) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
        title: '',
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function (e) {
        
        e.mb.target.removeAttribute('title')
        
        //infowindow.setContent(marker.title);
        //infowindow.open(map, marker);        
    }.bind(this)); 
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
        
        infowindow.close();
    }.bind(this));
    
   
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55, 11),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

new point(58, 14);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false"></script>
<section id="Map">
            <div id="googleMap" style="width:350px;height:600px;"></div>
        </section>
```

my solution is set to the content of the label is empty

Comment: Thanks, but I am using this as a WordPress plugin. So not sure if this script would work there.

Comment: I added your code but it does not work on my end. It does work on the fiddle, but like I said, I am using this as a WordPress plugin, so this code part does not remove the title tag as mentioned on the question.

Comment: @Nitesh.  let me know the plugin name.

Comment: Its Google Maps Users Add Markers

Comment: Could you please send me URL of the plugin?